# Calling a Category w/PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a PHP problem in WordPress while using a custom theme options panel.  I asked it on the WordPress site, but nobody could give me the right answer.

to_cat_home calls a category the user has selected from a theme options panel, to_count_home calls a number of posts the user has selected.

**The problem is the posts_per_page works but the cat= simply doesn't.**

**On the  archives pages the number of pages generated is determined by the basic WordPress settings, rather than the user selected number.**

```
<?php
$cat = get_option('to_cat_home');
$per_page = get_option('to_count_home');
query_posts("cat=${cat}&posts_per_page=${per_page}&paged=".$paged);
if (have_posts())
?>
```

In my functions:

```
array( "name" => "Homepage featured category",
    "desc" => "Choose a category from which featured posts are drawn",
    "id" => $shortname."_cat_home",
    "type" => "select",
    "options" => $wp_cats,
    "std" => "Choose a category"),
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is correct ? "cat=${cat}&posts_per_page=${per_page}&paged=".$paged). I think that this is correct "cat={$cat}&posts_per_page={$per_page}&paged=".$paged)

Comment: It still isn't pulling the category, but that code is written slightly better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
<?php
query_posts("cat={$cat}&posts_per_page={$per_page}&paged=".$paged);"
?>
```

Comment: This still isn't assigning the category.  Do you think the problem is the code I am using in the functions?  (See initial question)

Comment: actually, i'm just able to help you with plain php, I don't know much of, wp, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really do appreciate it!